# apply function on all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple function which detects if an element is in the viewport or that it is visible. If that element is visible, on every scroll I move that element down with `.css()` and change the top property to achieve some parallax effect. This element on which I check is in the viewport and when it moves it is repeated X times on the page. Everything works but only on the first element has this problem, all other elements inherit top position from the first.

Demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/RRVVwq (scroll down for effect).

EDIT: Some who answered had the wrong idea what I want, so I want the title (element) to move on scroll but only when its in viewport(visible). So when the first element with same class is visible its moving with scroll, then when you scroll below it its not visible anymore it should not move but the other one which is visible should be moving etc etc.

Jquery:

```
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  $.prototype.isVisible = function() {
    var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
      rect.bottom >= 0 &&
      rect.right >= 0 &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  };

  function doCheck() {
    var elementToDetect = $('.text');
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (elementToDetect.isVisible()) {
      elementToDetect.css('top', (-100 + (scrolled * 0.2)) + 'px');
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    doCheck();
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    doCheck();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery applies operations like `css()` on each element matching the selector.

So if you iterate the jQuery object, you get this:

```
  function doCheck() {
    var elementToDetect = $('.text');
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var index = 0; index < elementToDetect.length; index++) {
      var element = $(elementToDetect[index]);
      if (element.isVisible()) {
        element.css('top', (-100 + (scrolled * 0.2)) + 'px');
      }
    }
  }
```

Which still has a problem, in that all the text maintain the same top relative to their image.

**Edit:** 
Actually, the way I understand what you're doing, you want to let them all move in the same way as you scroll, so each starts above the image when it comes into view. This is closer to what you need:

```
  function doCheck() {
    var elementToDetect = $('.text');
    for (var index = 0; index < elementToDetect.length; index++) {
      var text = elementToDetect[index];
      var parent = text.parentElement;
      var parentTop = parent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var scrolled = (window.innerHeight - parentTop);
      if (scrolled < 0) {
        scrolled = 0;
      }
      if (parentTop < window.innerHeight) {
        $(text).css('top', (-100 + (scrolled * 0.2)) + 'px');
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, looking at `scrollTop()` is wrong, because you really want the position of the parent `div` to determine the placement of your text.

Comment: First one as you said has problems, while second is moving the title on every scroll, but i need to move only if element is visible. So the second example when you scroll to end, titles are way gone somewhere on the page. So none of this fixes are not working, but thanks for your time!!

Comment: Your initial question was about the way the jQuery command acts on all the text elements. I merely pointed out that you have another problem with text placement. I did now edit the answer to include a fix for your text placement.

Comment: Ok i now gave the second solution (Edit) another try and its now woking as i wanted

Comment: @riogrande I'm glad I could help. Please remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to check for each `.text` on the scroll:

```
function doCheck() {
  var elementToDetect = $('.text');
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  elementToDetect.each(function(i, txtEl) {
    if (txtEl.isVisible()) {
      txtEl.css('top', (-100 + (scrolled * 0.2)) + 'px');
    }
  });
}
```

And most likely you want to have a debouce there in the `window.scroll`:

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(timer){ clearTimeout(timer); }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
       doCheck();
    }, 900);
});
```

Comment: @Rajesh That is already a jQuery object, so no need to have a jquery wrapper there.

Comment: @Rajesh Your example does not work too, you see when you scroll all of titles are moving, not just the ones that are visible

Answer (score 0):

`$('.text')` returns an array of elements. You need to apply the css transform to each item rather than the array of items. The below code may require an update to get the output you would like but I think it should get you going.

```
function doCheck() {
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.text').each(function() {
    if($(this).isVisible()) {
      $(this).css('top', (-100 + (scrolled * 0.2)) + 'px');
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not working, try opening my codepen and replace my function with yours and you will see, its worse than my try, but thanks for your time!!

Comment: I haven't time to look in more depth right now but I suspect the offset needs to be worked out from the top of each parent element / image rather than solely using scrollTop